# Ultimate members produce un error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: wordpress, plugins, ultimate-member

I have a website https://iose36c4.com that, upon enabling the ULTIMATE MEMBERS plugin, produces an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. I've already tried correcting the "wp-config.php" and ".htaccess" files, but the issue persists, and only when I deactivate the ULTIMATE MEMBERS plugin does it start working again. The problem is that when I disable this plugin, I cannot segment the website content according to user roles.

I want to use the Ultimate Members plugin to make certain posts accessible to specific user roles, but when testing the site on other browsers, it gives an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.

Comment: Have you reached out to the Ultimate Members support team to ask about this yet? If not it might be a good idea to do so as this is probably a common problem and they surely know how to fix it.